# How to get the result of the AHK script execution in PHP?

Tags: php, autohotkey

This is my simple AHK script:

```
MsgBox % "Hello world"
ExitApp, 7777
```

I run this AHK from PHP by following code:

```
$result = exec('start path\ahk.exe', $output, $result_code);
```

And now I want to get some data from ahk.exe. But when I dump variables:

```
var_dump($result, $output, $result_code);
```

The result is:

```
string(0) "" array(0) { } int(0)
```

All variables are empty. So, how I can get some usefull data after execution ahk.exe?

Comment: What useful data are you trying to get? What does the command output?

Comment: @alex-howansky as you see I cant get any output, and dont know why, So lets say I want to get string "Hello World" from this script. How I can get this data in my php script?

Comment: The fact that both `$result` and `$output` are empty here implies that your command doesn't output anything. If you run `start path\ahk.exe` manually from a command prompt, what does it print?

Comment: @alex-howansky also nothing, so what should I do to make the script return a value?

Comment: [From docs:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/MsgBox.htm) "Displays the specified text in a small window containing one or more buttons (such as Yes and No)." What are you expecting to be in the captured output? A popup? That's not how that works. You need to find a function that prints something to console if you want PHP to be able to read it, but it doesn't look like AHK is too keen on actually supporting something like that. Given that this is running on Windows, you're also going to a bad time passing data to/from PHP, which is very linux-centric.

Comment: @sammitch This program should be for windows, not linux. So I expect that there is some workaround for this

Answer (score 0):

You could store the results in a text file then in PHP read the text file.

```
FileOpen, output.txt, w
FileWrite, % "Hello World"
FileClose, output.txt
ExitApp, 7777
```

Then in PHP call the exec function, wait for the file to be created and then use `file_get_contents` to get the results.

Comment: Is there a way to transfer data directly from ahk.exe to php script? File in the middle looks not best solution

Comment: Looking online there is something called AutoHotkey Pipe, never seen it or used it but it might do this. It would require some investigation from yourself. [See Link](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/23575-how-to-run-dynamic-script-through-a-pipe/) not sure how you would do the PHP part though

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: **Looks like I got it in reverse**. I thought you wanted your PHP result in AHK but looks like you want your AHK result in PHP. Still, the concept below should help you since AHK can write to StdOut using the `FileAppend` command with the asterisk (`*`) for the Filename which causes Text to be sent to standard output (stdout) (but check help - not in the current console window which doesn't matter with my technique).

It can be done, but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Just sending "Hello World" to the console?  Can PHP use StdOut?

If so, you could use the `WScript.Shell` then pass the command in the `.Exec(ComSpec " /C cscript " command)` method and return the `exec.StdOut.ReadAll()`

I have a working example as follows, maybe it helps you:

```
;// The following AHK script runs a command (add.vbs but yours would be the PHP script?) 
;// and retrieves its output via StdOut:

InputBox, x,,"Enter two numbers" ;//asks for two ints to pass to script
MsgBox % """" RunWaitOne("add.vbs " x) """" ;// result in quotes in a ahk msgbox
ExitApp

RunWaitOne(command) ;// this is the function
{
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C cscript /nologo " command)
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}

/* This is the external "add.vbs" command used in example (replace with yours):
a=3
b=4
if WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    a=cint(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    b=cint(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
End If
Dim StdOut : Set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)
x=a+b
StdOut.Write x
*/
```

Hth,